# Merge many csv files with similar names

Tags: linux, csv, concatenation, python-3.6

I have many csv files in a particular format like 1file1.csv 2file1.csv 3file2.csv 4file2.csv 5file3.csv 6file3.csv and so on.

I want to merge all the files which have the same digit at the end of filename. Example 1file1.csv and 2file1.csv should be concatenated. Similarly, 3file2.csv and 4file2.csv should be concatenated.

Are there any linux commands to do it?
Or an optimised python code?

Comment: It can probably be done in bash, but when it comes to string processing (same digit at the end of the name) it would be easier to write, test and maintain it in Python. Just an opinion so only a comment.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Okay. So do you know of any package in python? Or a sample code would do.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution in bash:

```
printf "%s\n" [0-9]*file[0-9]*.csv | sed 's/.*file//;' | sort -u | xargs -I{} -- sh -c 'cat [0-9]*file{} > output_file{}'
```

Files 1file1.csv 2file1.csv will be concatenated in output_file1.csv
Files 3file2.csv 4file2.csv  will be concatenated in output_file2.csv

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!